# Types of terms that can be added using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

This is a question about what forms of new Lagrangian are valid after we alter an original Lagrangian to add Lagrange multipliers.

Say we have some constraint $g(x,y)=0$ that we want to add to our Lagrangian $L(x,y)$ using Lagrange multipliers to form a new Lagrangian $\bar{L}(x,y,\lambda)$ as

$$ \bar{L}=L(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y) \label{1}\tag{1}$$

My understanding here is that, whenever we add such a constraint, it has to be such that the new and old Lagrangian are the same if we directly impose out knowledge that $g=0$. That is, equation \eqref{1} above has $g=0$ and therefore we have not fundamentally altered $L$. If we then carry on with the optimization with $\lambda$ included as variable, we get the usual treatment of Lagrange multipliers.

Now let's say the constraint is of the form $x=\bar{x}$ and $y=\bar{y}$, where $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ is another pair of variables, we can then talk about a new Lagrangian of the form
$$ \bar{L}=L(x,y)+\lambda_{1}(x-\bar{x})+\lambda_{2}(y-\bar{y}), \label{2}\tag{2}$$
which, again, seems OK to me, because we wouldn't fundamentally alter the old $L$ by this formulation.

My question now is, can we add another term that will alter $L$ to be written mixed variables like:
$$ \bar{L}=L(x,y)+L(\bar{x},\bar{y})+\lambda_{1}(x-\bar{x})+\lambda_{2}(y-\bar{y}), \label{3}\tag{3}$$
where the first two terms on the RHS are the same function but in different variables.

My initial feeling is that this should work, because if we enforce $x=\bar{x}$ and $y=\bar{y}$ then the the Lagrangian will be the same old form, except for a scalar multiplier of \eqref{2}, which shouldn't alter the dynamics. Does that make sense?

Comment: If the bar decoration denotes that the functions are fixed, then the term will have no contribution to the variation of the modified Lagrangian of (3) (a fixed function won't be varied). The Lagrangian evaluated at all (x,y) will be offset by a constant.

Comment: @arnold Sorry, I should have clarified the notation. I have updated the question. The overbar quantities are just another set of variables, but not fixed.

Comment: What's the motivation for modifying the Lagrangian the way you have?Additionally, if the overbar quantities are variables in (2), they seem to be superfluous and do not constrain the choice of your (x,y).

Comment: @arnold The motivation is that I know the full solution of the system governed by the first Lagrangian $L(x,y)$, but I then have another related problem whose Lagrangian has the form $L(x,y) + L(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ (so it has similar form but with additional variables). And I am trying to find a way to link the two. One suggestion was that we can "pretend" to use Lagrange multipliers for this purpose. But I wanted to ensure that this formulation is sound to start with. If so, then we can proceed to work with that new Lagrangian and so forth (e.g., find the new Hamiltonian, etc)...

Comment: If the relations $x=\bar x$ and $y=\bar y$ are to hold, it's entirely equivalent to express either of these variables in terms of the other rather than using Lagrange multipliers. In this case, the effect would be to double your Lagrangian, which does nothing to change the variational problem. Lagrange multipliers are used in part because they preserve a symmetry of the equation and because they can simply the expression tremendously, but neither benefit is relevant here. Are the forms of the Lagrangians you're summing the same, as your notation implies?

Comment: One case I can imagine where this approach would be relevant is comparing the Lagrangian of a system of n bodies to that of a system of m bodies, m>n. But in identifying the n bodies to the m-n bodies (where m must then equal 2n), you haven't changed the system at all, just scaled everything in a trivial way. You would need a method that doesn't identify the bodies, no?

Comment: @arnold 1/2: You are right, the two Lagrangians being summed are somewhat different, but I tried to ask the question in generality (in retrospect, maybe wasn't the best idea). Basically when we don't use overbars, we have harmonic expressions in $L$ that follow the $\sin$ function, while when we work in terms of the overbarred ones (the added term) the $L$ replaces the $\sin$ by $\cos$ functions. We already have the solution for the first case, and the second case is only different by how these sines are switched to cosines inside the Lagrangian, and ....

Comment: @arnold 2/2: ... I wish to not solve the entire system again (equations of motion). Instead, we wish to glean the expected answer for the second case from our knowledge of the solution of the first case. I think this should be reasonable to do in principle, but I am trying to find a simple way to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120974/discussion-between-arnold-and-user135626).